# What are the triple circles on the HUD in Warframe?

Tags: warframe

What do the triple circles in a triangle configuration on the left side of each player tag signify?  They come and go during the game, but I haven't figured out what they mean.  Also, what does the 3 under mine mean?

[image]

Comment: I can't say for certain, but I think that might be the Shared Affinity range icon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Wondercricket said: 
The top-most three-circle-icon next to your shield and health numbers is **shown if you are in affinity sharing range** with another squad member. The number 3 below that tells you **how many squad members are in range** to share affinity. If one of them is out of range then there is no icon next to their name.

The wiki page for [Affinity](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Affinity) says:

> Be near an allied Tenno when they kill an enemy. When within 50 meters of an ally when they kill an enemy, you gain the same total Affinity, split according to your own weaponry. This doesn't reduce the Affinity gained by the killing player, and doesn't reduce the Affinity gained by other nearby allies.

Comment: I didn't get far enough to Warframe to know if that was it or not, that is just what I gather by research :). The op also want to know what the white number means as well, which I'm guessing is the number of players in range (hence why the other players have the icon as well)

Comment: You're correct. I adjusted my wording and added emphasis to hopefully make the answer clearer.